# Property Render Snippet for a Redirected Google Plus Page

Tags: persistence, google-plus, doi

I want to post a link, either through the website or through the API for a plus one to a DOI.  For those unfamiliar with this, a DOI is a stable link to a publication (see http://www.doi.org/faq.html).  When this is entered it redirects you via a 303 redirect to the publisher's website version of the paper.  For example:

```
curl -i http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cryobiol.2012.06.009
```

resolves

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0011224012001241
Expires: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 10:09:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 208
Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2012 15:28:31 GMT


<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Handle Redirect</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><A HREF="http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0011224012001241">http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0011224012001241</A></BODY></HTML>
```

Unfortunately the metadata for a plus-one snippet is derived from the target url, and as far as I can tell it cannot be provided separately. From https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet:

> Populating the +Snippet
>
> After clicking the +1 button, the user is given the option to share
>   the page to Google+ via a displayed share bubble. This share bubble
>   with the resulting Google+ activity post includes a preview, or
>   +Snippet, that contains the page title, a brief description of the page, and a thumbnail image. These pieces of data are extracted from
>   content found at the target URL and can be easily specified by the
>   content publisher.
>
> For detailed information and to customize your own snippet, see the
>   snippet documentation.

The problem is that it is better to link to the DOI for aggregation purposes, since the DOI is stable while the journal website link may not be.  Is there anyway to use the DOI for the link with google plus and still populate the popup correctly?

Comment: When registering an article with the DOI service, are you just registering a URL, or does it also have additional information (Journal name, Article name, summary, picture)?

Comment: The article is generally registered by a publisher.  There is additional information then provided from that publisher.  This metadata can be accessed programatically by asking for something other than html See http://crosscite.org/cn/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the best solution would be to have doi.org have its redirect page publish some of the metadata information on the 303 page (where the link currently is). This way bots that follow the link will get the information from the final target page, while those that don't will still be able to get metadata from the redirect page.

Comment: But I have no control over the DOI system, nor do i have control over whether Google+ can traverse the 303 redirect.  I was hoping there might be a way to make Google+ do a content negotiation request for json to get the correct metadata.